# How to get AutoFixture working for immutable classes with tree like structure?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

This small test here:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class TreeXTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldCreateSmallTree()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior(3));
        fixture.Behaviors.OfType<ThrowingRecursionBehavior>().ToList()
            .ForEach(b => fixture.Behaviors.Remove(b));

        // Act
        var em = fixture.Create<TreeX>();

        // Assert
        em.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```

Works fine when I have classes defined like this:

```cs
class TreeX
{
    public MetaX MetaX { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<TreeX> Children { get; set; }

    public TreeX OtherTreePointer { get; set; }
}

class MetaX
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}
```

But when I add constructors and remove public setters:

```cs
class TreeX
{
    public TreeX(MetaX metaX, IReadOnlyList<TreeX> children, TreeX otherTreePointer = null)
    {
        MetaX = metaX;
        Children = children;
        OtherTreePointer = otherTreePointer;
    }

    public MetaX MetaX { get; }

    public IReadOnlyList<TreeX> Children { get; }

    public TreeX OtherTreePointer { get; }
}

class MetaX
{
    public MetaX(int a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public int A { get; }
}
```

It fails with the following error:

> AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath: AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from TreeX, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.

Which is not really helpful.

Also I found that if I remove `OtherTreePointer` from `TreeX` then it works again:

```cs
class TreeX
{
    public TreeX(MetaX metaX, IReadOnlyList<TreeX> children)
    {
        MetaX = metaX;
        Children = children;
    }

    public MetaX MetaX { get; }

    public IReadOnlyList<TreeX> Children { get; }
}
```

...but I really need `OtherTreePointer`. I don't want to redesign my classes and immutability is a must.

I'm not sure whether this is an issue with the library, but if not then how can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not have two constructors, one with `TreeX otherTreePointer` and the other without? Or use a static factory? Or a subclass that uses a separate `protected` constructor?

Comment: `AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from TreeX, [...], is an abstract or non-public type`. have you tried `public class TreeX` because the default is `internal` rather than `public`.

Comment: I have the same problem, and it's not because some class is internal. It doesn't matter, that is not the root cause. AutoFixture get's totally lost when a type is "self referencing". I've been fighting this for a while now. I even posted a question here on SO (only after posting it, did SO remind me of your question...)